# Rails 3.2 UJS -> Can it grab the ID for me for a dynamic URL?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

I need to construct the POST url for a resouce and the val() of the item that I am adding remote-true to will be the ID in the URL resource. IS there a rails shortcut for doing this or do I just have to do

```
  data: {'id': $(this).val()}
```

in the jQuery ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood your problem, but I guess you want to achieve this

```
data: {'id': '<%= params[:id] %>'}
```

You can access the id contained in the url with `params[:id]` and embed this in your javascript snippet (unless it is in a .js file).

Is this addressing your problem? If not can you please clarify / rephrase?

Comment: Pierre, the id should be the jQuery val() of the DOM element which kicked off the event. If a select box, the val will contain a DB ID that should be used in the construction of the URL.

Comment: OK cool, that's what I thought. You could do it with the old prototype helpers but not with the new jQuery ones.

Comment: I'll mark you as correct since you confirmed my suspicion in the comments :)